# Django how to avoid duplicate email usage at registration?

Tags: django, django-registration

I am new to Django and use [Django-Registration](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-registration) module. It forbids username ducplicates but how to make it to forbid email duplication too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django-Registration provides many different registration forms.

And specially a [RegistrationFormUniqueEmail](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/tip/registration/forms.py#cl-79) that will fit your need.

Comment: Great. Just added     url(r'^register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=RegistrationFormUniqueEmail),
    name='registration_register'), to the urls.py and voila.